How can I remove points that do not belong to a shared surface within a pointcloud?
My program finds points along the bottom surface of a 3D object. The objects are of a unique shape. I am able to get the points on the bottom surface, but some extraneous points remain that are clearly not part of the bottom surface. How to remove or ignore them?
Using the Open3D library in Python it relies on extracting only vertices with negative normals to a point cloud. My reasoning was that points along the underside of the object would only have negative normals.
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("mypath")
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
vertex_normals = np.asarray(mesh.vertex_normals)
vertices = np.asarray(mesh.vertices)

underside_indices = np.where(vertex_normals[:, 2] < 0)[0]
underside_points = vertices[underside_indices]
underside_point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
underside_point_cloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(underside_points)
#Remove outliers
cl, ind = underside_point_cloud.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=40, std_ratio=2.0)
clean_underside_point_cloud = underside_point_cloud.select_by_index(ind)
#Compute the centroid of the mesh and Visualize
centroid = mesh.get_center()
centroid_sphere = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere(radius=1)
centroid_sphere.translate(centroid)
centroid_sphere.paint_uniform_color([1, 0, 0])
#Visualization
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([clean_underside_point_cloud, centroid_sphere])

Under the red line are the points along the bottom surface of the object, the points above the red line are not part of the bottom surface. The red sphere denotes the centroid of the object.
Point cloud. STL model.
Front view:

Side view:

Top view (notice the continuous surface under the random spurts of points above it):

Underside:

